# How can I play Blu-Ray movies on a PC upgraded to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center, blu-ray

How can I play Blu-Ray movies via Windows Media Centre on Windows 8? If I choose the "play dvd" option, I get an error:

> Cannot Play Disc
>
> To play this DVD, you must first install a playback application that supports Blu-ray Disc.
>
> [ OK ]

However, I have got the HP MediaSmart application installed, which does work (although it's "less than awesome"), so I'm confused why I get this warning?

Comment: I think it is extremely strange that Microsoft doesn't prioritise Windows Media Centre (my personal favourite application, which I use daily to watch movies from DVB-T and DVD) as a platform for home cinema. The WMC interface is superior to any third-party application. I don't want to use any other application to watch movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [an article on Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-8-dvd-playback-app-compatibility,3341.html):

> [...] the Media Center Pack does not include codecs for Blu-ray playback.

You need to obtain (read: buy, as Blu-Ray codecs cost money) a separate application to be able to play Blu-Ray discs. In your case, you should use *HP MediaSmart* to play your videos.

Comment: I have HP MediaSmart (as mentioned in the question). Why doesn't that count?

Comment: You have to use this application to play the movie. Media Center obviously won't "borrow" codecs from it.

Comment: Are you saying it's just a badly worded message, and that it should tell me to use that application (that it implies is not yet installed)

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: But what if the user really wants to use WMC to play blue-ray movies?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand : "But what if the user really wants to use WMC to play blue-ray movies?" - Well, then the user is **out of luck**. :)

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: How do you expect Windows Media Player to divine the fact that an entirely different application already installed is able to play BluRays?

Comment: @SecurityMatt I expect codecs to be shared between applications, in the same that they are for DVDs.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Codecs are not shared between applications even before Windows8.

Comment: @SecurityMatt They *can* be (and are in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

You get this warning because:

- a Blu-ray isn't a DVD and
- Windows Media Center might not have the correct codecs installed for Blu-ray

The warning states that you don't have a correct application to view it, not the correct drive, which is is why your Blu-ray does work with HP MediaSmart.

If you're unhappy with it try VLC. I don't have a Blu-ray myself but a quick Google of the keywords "VLC Blu-ray" tells me that it is possible.